# Scala: pattern matching Option[Class[_]]

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Surely there's a more concise way to switch on an Option of Class type than:

```
// Return an object of the given class type:
def badFactory( clazz: Option[Class[_]]): AnyRef = {
    clazz match {
      case Some(foo) if foo == classOf[Foo] => new Foo()

      case Some(bar) if bar == classOf[Bar] => new Bar()
    }
  }
```

Note: if clazz is 1) None or 2) Some but neither Foo nor Bar, I expect it to throw.

Comment: Can you clarify what is supposed to happen when `clazz` is 1) `None` or 2) `Some` but neither `Foo` nor `Bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. If you put them into `val`s beforehand (names must start with upper case) you can have

```
val FooClass = classOf[Foo]
val BarClass = classOf[Bar]
// Return an object of the given class type:
def badFactory( clazz: Option[Class[_]]): AnyRef = {
    clazz match {
      case Some(FooClass) => new Foo()
      case Some(BarClass) => new Bar()
      case _ => ...
    }
  }
```

Or avoid repeating `Some`:

```
// Return an object of the given class type:
def badFactory( clazz: Option[Class[_]]): AnyRef = {
    clazz match {
      case Some(clazz2) => 
        if (clazz2 == classOf[Foo])
          new Foo()
        else if (clazz2 == classOf[Bar])
          new Bar()
        else ...
      case None => ...
    }
  }
```